# How to hide a div section when user is logged in, in single product woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, css

I have the next issue: I have a promotional banner to show a discount on every single product but I want to hide this banner when the user is logged in, I have tried different codes buy anyone was worked for me, how I can hide this banner for logged in users and show only for logged out?

The banner is this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the user logged in to WordPress then the `logged-in` class added in `body tag`.

Suppose if you have a div as:

```
<div class="hide_div_user_login">
some content here
</div>
```

Put this CSS in the `style.css` file.

```
.logged-in .hide_div_user_login{
 display:none;
}
```

Hope it will work for you.